# Div Print using unobtrusive javascript

Tags: .net-core, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a Print link where I want to print a printer friendly section of a View page. I don't want to print the menus but just a certain div id using unobtrusive javascript. How do I do that?

Printer-Friendly link:

```
                  <a class="list-group-item"
                   asp-area="Admin"
                   asp-controller="Employee"
                   asp-action="View"
                   asp-route-id="@currentId"   title="Print">Printer-Friendly Version</a>
```

View page that I want to print:

```
            <div id="divPrint" class="col-md-8">
                 <h2>Administration</h2>
                 <h4>View the Document</h4>
                   <div class="card">
                   <div class="card-body">
                   <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span><b>@Model.Current.Title</b> as of <b>@Model.Current.AsOf.ToString("dddd, 
                    dd MMMM yyyy")</b></span>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                </div> 
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css to hide all the elements that you don't wan't to print with `@media print` and `visibility: hidden;` and for safe measure you can specify what you do want to print with `visibility: visible;`.

Within `@media print`, you can also specify styling only for printing. If you have white text on dark background, you can add `p { color: #000000; }` so it is more printer friendly.

```css
@media print {
  .classes-to-not-print, div, nav {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  .classes-to-print, #divPrint {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

Comment: OK I added this to my css. How do I get the Printer friendly link to call the css, I guess?

Comment: The above `@media print` only needs to be linked from the page that it is printing. You might need to add this to your print link `onclick="window.print()"` so that your link will look similar to this:
`<a class="list-group-item"
                   onclick="window.print()"
                   asp-area="Admin"
                   asp-controller="Employee"
                   asp-action="View"
                   asp-route-id="@currentId"   title="Print">Printer-Friendly Version</a>`

Comment: I can't use onclick. I need to use unobtrusive javascript.

Comment: This would depend on how your `#divPrint` is generated. Where ever you can style the `#divPrint` i would put the `@media print` in the same .css file, or if you have in page css put it in the `<style></style>` tags.

`<style>@media print{}</style>
<div id="divPrint" class="col-md-8">`